# Voted to reopen due to incorrect closure reason

Tags: discussion

I voted to reopen [this philosophical question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273254/are-fact-and-opinion-mutually-exclusive) (Opinion vs. Fact).

I do agree it could be off-topic for this site, despite the fact I have enjoyed the experience of thinking about it and providing an answer on it. I agree it is probably on-topic on the Philosophy SE (though I have not studied their charter).

What I disagree with is that it has been closed as a duplicate of an answered question. I don't think it is the same question *at all* though there is a superficial similarity. The original question was about the English sentence construction of "incorrect fact" and whether that is an oxymoron. I certainly agree with the accepted answer on that question.

This question is about whether it is philosophically acceptable to have an opinion on a demonstrable fact or whether such a circumstance has any meaning.

Merely stating that something that is a "fact" cannot *by definition* be incorrect says nothing about whether one can have an opinion on a fact.

Therefore I assert it has been incorrectly closed and should be reopened.

Whether it is off-topic or not should be decided by the community using the usual process.

Comment: What do you think the closure reason should be?

Comment: I think it should be off-topic with a note to the OP that it might be on-topic at Philosophy SE.

Comment: That's not very helpful though, when pointing at a related question might be. It's still possible to comment about being more on-topic elsewhere. Also: the question is already closed. There's no point in re-opening only to close it again.

Comment: Is it really less helpful to send an OP to a place ideally suited for their question than to let them (and subsequent visitors) believe the other question holds the right answer when, in fact, it doesn't? Side question: How come it only took two votes to close the question, rather than the more normal number (4 isn't it?), I have seen this before and it always puzzled me @AndrewLeach

Comment: A moderator's close vote (indicated by a diamond) is binding.

Comment: The moderator in this case is the same person who supplied the accepted answer to the first question. There could have been undue haste there which bypassed the more normal procedure of allowing the community to judge the correct closure method. Just saying. I'll let it go now.

Comment: I fully agree. I see how the two questions are slightly related, but they are still very different. Questions shouldn't be closed for the wrong reasons. Whether it should have been closed for another reason is irrelevant, so I don't understand why it's used as an argument here.

Comment: I vote to reopen, but not because the VTC reason was inappropriate, but because it is a valid question about the usage and the meaning between *fact* and *opinion*. It *is* a language question, the OP even cites MW. What is your "off topic" reason? Lack of research? It should be migrated to ELL? It belongs to philosophy?  Or something else?

Comment: MISINFORMATION ALERT! The two users who voted to close the question are NOT moderators. Moderators are identifiable by their black diamond symbol. This has to do with superpowers. When a user earns a gold badge in SWR (tags) they can cast a super vote. It's been handled on meta somewhere. I'll find it.... here: [A single vote closes a question! Have I just been granted “superpowers”?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4807/a-single-vote-closes-a-question-have-i-just-been-granted-superpowers)

Comment: FWIW I think it is actually more of a philosophical question that a pure English usage question and that is why I think it is off-topic here. however I would probably not have CV it as off-topic. Apologies on the mis-information, that was 100% my mistake but in my defence I was not aware of the ways the system indicates the seniority of the closers.

Comment: I have edited the question here to reflect my changed opinion that it should be reopened because it was incorrectly closed and have de-emphasised my view that it is off-topic which I agree is irrelevant to that reason.